# PHP Echo XML Attributes Without Repeating

Tags: php, xml, echo, repeat

my question has to do with PHP and XML. I would like to echo out some attributes, but echo ones that repeat only once.

Say this was the XML I was dealing with, and it was called beatles.xml:

```
<XML_DATA item=“TheBeatles”>
    <Beatles>
       <Beatle Firstname=“George” Lastname=“Harrison” Instrument=“Guitar”>Harrison, George</Beatle>
       <Beatle Firstname=“John” Lastname=“Lennon” Instrument=“Guitar”>Lennon, John</Beatle>
       <Beatle Firstname=“Paul” Lastname=“McCartney” Instrument=“Bass”>McCartney, Paul</Beatle>
       <Beatle Firstname=“Ringo” Lastname=“Starr” Instrument=“Drums”>Starr, Ringo</Beatle>
    </Beatles>
</XML_DATA>
```

This is the PHP I have so far:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com/beatles.xml");
$beatles = $xml->Beatles->Beatle;

foreach($beatles as $beatle) {
echo $beatle->attributes()->Instrument.','; 
}
```

I would expect this to echo out Guitar,Guitar,Bass,Drums, but I would like Guitar to only display once. How would I prevent repeat attribute values from echoing out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `foreach` loop, cast the instrument name as a string and push it into an array. Once the loop finishes execution, you will have an array containing all the instrument names (with duplicates, of course). You can now use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) to filter out the duplicate values from the array:

```
$instruments = array();

foreach($beatles as $beatle) {
    $instruments[] = (string) $beatle->attributes()->Instrument; 
}

$instruments = array_unique($instruments);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/77684)

Comment: Thank you! This got me the exact result I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com/beatles.xml");
    $beatles = $xml->Beatles->Beatle;
    $result = array();
    foreach($beatles as $beatle) {
    
        if (!array_key_exists($beatle->attributes()->Instrument, $result)) {
            $result[] = $beatle->attributes()->Instrument;
            // echo $beatle->attributes()->Instrument.',';
        }

}
```

then Loop through the `$result` array with `foreach`

Either use [xpath](https://www.php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath).